# Mule create wsdl on http endpoint

Tags: http, wsdl, esb, mule

I am wondering if Mule will create a wsdl on a http endpoint so I can access it through soapUI.  I am passing in xml with a soap envelope, like what follows.  I don't have a wsdl created, but I have a flow afterwards to read and use this xml being passed in.  I know with other ESB tools it's possible to say this endpoint needs to expose a wsdl, and it'll create one for you on build. Does mule do anything like this?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <lookup>
        <bookid>0028634748</bookid>
    </lookup>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mule can generate a WSDL on-the-fly but it needs **something** to infer the WSDL from. It can be done from a pure POJO component without any need for JAX-WS annotations and is configured like this:

```
<flow name="bookLookupService">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8181/bls"
        exchange-pattern="request-response">
        <cxf:simple-service serviceClass="com.acme.BookLookupService" />
    </http:inbound-endpoint>
    <component class="com.acme.BookLookupServiceImpl" />
</flow>
```

With the following interface:

```
package com.acme;

public interface BookLookupService
{
    public static class BookLookup
    {
        private String bookid;

        public String getBookid()
        {
            return bookid;
        }

        public void setBookid(final String bookid)
        {
            this.bookid = bookid;
        }
    }

    public static class Book
    {
        private String bookid, name;

        public String getBookid()
        {
            return bookid;
        }

        public void setBookid(final String bookid)
        {
            this.bookid = bookid;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(final String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    Book lookup(final BookLookup bookLookup);
}
```

and implementation:

```
package com.acme;

public class BookLookupServiceImpl implements BookLookupService
{
    public Book lookup(final BookLookup bookLookup)
    {
        final Book book = new Book();
        book.setName("LOTR");
        book.setBookid(bookLookup.getBookid());
        return book;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the WSDL will not conform to the expected message above, you end up with messages like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:acme="http://acme.com/" xmlns:acme1="http://acme.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <acme:lookup>
         <acme:arg0>
            <acme1:bookid>ABC123</acme1:bookid>
         </acme:arg0>
      </acme:lookup>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

If you want stricter control on the generated WSDL you'll have to use JAX-WS / JAXB annotations.

Comment: Not what I was hoping for, but it answers the question and provides a solution to the problem.  I had hoped endpoints would play nicer in creating a WSDL for a flow.  Instead of just the bottom up or top down approach for creating web services.  There could be other ways, but thank you for the answer.

Comment: Alternatively, you could craft the WSDL by hand (since apparently there is nothing Mule/CXF can infer it from) and serve it on GET requests to the HTTP endpoint. But again, this doesn't do the automagic WSDL generation you're after :)